# How to Receive Inputs via Code from a Separate window

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, console-application

I am attempting to write a c# console app (In VS) that will open (joy.cpl) Game controllers menu and look at the properties of a joystick. Now in the properties, I am attempting to get the input from the test section. Essentially, there is a window that has two buttons which illuminate when a button is clicked. Is there a way to acquire information from a separate window that there is a state change  (In the properties test window) that each button was clicked?

[Single Button Press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tosF.png)

Here is the sample of code. Everything works as expected except for the Button section. I want to get the values of each press and then save that in a variable but I am not quite sure if it is possible in c#.

**CODE**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using WindowsInput;
using WindowsInput.Native;

public class GameControllerSetup
{
      private InputSimulator inputSimulator;
      private bool isButton1Pressed;
      private bool isButton2Pressed;

public GameControllerSetup()
{
    // Initialize InputSimulator
    inputSimulator = new InputSimulator();
}

public void OpenPropertiesOfMotorolaDesktopMicrophone()
{
    // Start the "Set up USB game controllers" window
    Process.Start("joy.cpl");

    // Delay to allow the window to open
    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    // Send key combination to open the properties tab
    inputSimulator.Keyboard.KeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.TAB);
    inputSimulator.Keyboard.KeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.TAB);
    inputSimulator.Keyboard.KeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);
    inputSimulator.Keyboard.KeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);

    // Perform LED automation before closing properties tab
    PerformLedAutomation();

    // Delay to allow the properties tab to open
    Thread.Sleep(7000);

    // Wait until both buttons are pressed
    while (!(isButton1Pressed && isButton2Pressed))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    // Send key combination to close properties tab and close game controller menu
    inputSimulator.Keyboard.KeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);
    inputSimulator.Keyboard.KeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);
    Thread.Sleep(200);
    inputSimulator.Keyboard.KeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.TAB);
    inputSimulator.Keyboard.KeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.TAB);
    Thread.Sleep(200);
    inputSimulator.Keyboard.KeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.TAB);
    inputSimulator.Keyboard.KeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.TAB);
    Thread.Sleep(200);
    inputSimulator.Keyboard.KeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);
    inputSimulator.Keyboard.KeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);

    // Delay to allow the properties tab to close
    Thread.Sleep(100);

    // Exit the application
    Environment.Exit(0);
}

private void PerformLedAutomation()
{
    // Perform LED automation logic here
    // Example: Check the state of the LEDs and update the button pressed flags
    // Place your LED automation code here

    // Simulating button presses for testing purposes
    SimulateButtonPress(1);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    SimulateButtonPress(2);
}

private void SimulateButtonPress(int buttonNumber)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Button {buttonNumber} pressed.");
    if (buttonNumber == 1)
    {
        isButton1Pressed = true;
    }
    else if (buttonNumber == 2)
    {
        isButton2Pressed = true;
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GameControllerSetup setup = new GameControllerSetup();
    setup.OpenPropertiesOfMotorolaDesktopMicrophone();

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you are saying, but doing a `Thread.Sleep(1000);` on the UI thread in a Winforms app is a bad idea; your UI freezes for a second. Make things `async` and then `await Task.Delay(1000);` will be much more satisfying